# scala how to create array of size using length of another array of different type

Tags: arrays, scala

I am trying to create an array of Char using another array of Int's size. Code doesn't compile:

```
object Main {      
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {        
    val mapping = Map(1 -> "ABC", 2 -> "DEF")    
    val a = mapping.keySet.toArray    
    val c = Array[Char](a.length)
  }   
}
```

The compiler throws an error: "type mismatch; found : Int required: Char"

when I change the code above to:

```
val c = Array[Char](2) // no compiler error
```

Looks like the compiler is interpreting my input not as a size param but instead thinking it's a Char such as an initial element of the Char array

Since in java this code would compile without a problem I was wondering
what's the proper way of using another array length as a size param to init a different array in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `.ofDim` in your last line

```
val c = Array.ofDim[Char](a.length)
```

The second one works

```
val c = Array[Char](2)
```

as the compiler is treating 2 itself as a character.

Answer (score 3):

**Array** type in scala has one confusing aspect, let me help you clarify it:

1.Array type has **a class and a object**, the object is called **companion object** for the specific class.

2.object Array has **an apply method** which in the code you use, `but` it can not be construct the same as the companion class.

**To this snippet of code, the solution is:**

```
object Main {      
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {        
    val mapping = Map(1 -> "ABC", 2 -> "DEF")    
    val a = mapping.keySet.toArray    
    val c = new Array[Char](a.length)
  }   
}
```

**Please be careful about the change of it, add `new` keyword to the created Array class.**